# How to use delegate here? I can't get it to work

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, delegates

I know there is very simple question, but few hours I can not do this.

I got 2 classes: 
1. LoginViewController : UIViewController 
2.  WebRequests : NSObject - it makes request and got response from server (singleton)

Then I got response I want to run MyMethod in LoginViewController from WebRequests.

I do it like here, but it not works:

WebRequests.h

```
@protocol WebRequestsDelagate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) MyMethod;
@end

@interface WebRequests : NSObject
...
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <WebRequestsDelagate> delegate;
```

WebRequests.m

```
@implementation WebRequests

//singleton
 + (WebRequests *)sharedInstance {
 static dispatch_once_t p = 0;
__strong static id _sharedObject = nil;

dispatch_once(&p, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
});

return _sharedObject;
}

- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    LoginViewController * loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
     self.delegate = loginViewController;
}
return self;
}

- (void) someMethod {
//here I got response
[self.delegate runThisMethod];
```

I do not move on in runThisMethod in LoginViewController.

Why does it not work?

UPDATE

```
@implementation LoginViewController 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}
```

//  AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Post your controller code.  (One) reason it's not working is that you create a `LoginViewController` object but nowhere is it presented.  Can't say more based only on this code.

Comment: I post it, I use segue and I think not I create it with appropriate conditions

Comment: Post the code where the singleton is accessed, ie, where `sharedInstance` is called.  I have a hunch it's in `LoginViewController`.  Also take a look at @trojanfoe's answer.

Comment: @jcm, ye, he helps me, can you help me too? how then I need to call sharedInstance if I create instance of WebRequests in LoginViewController? I mean like class method or like instance, because class not works with trojanfoe's answer

Comment: How do you call `sharedInstance` currently?

Comment: @jcm, yes, I create              self.webRequests = [[WebRequests alloc] init];
            self.webRequests.delegate = self; in LoginViewController viewDidload and than call     [[WebRequests sharedInstance] myMethod];
 from LoginViewController

Comment: WebRequests contain just       [self.delegate runThisMethod];
 without any other declaration

Comment: Okay, add `LoginController`'s `viewDidLoad` to the question.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
             self.webRequests = [[WebRequests alloc] init];
            self.webRequests.delegate = self;   
}

Comment: @jcm, interface LoginViewController : property (strong, nonatomic)  WebRequests *webRequests; Maybe this bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* that's your real code, then the `loginViewController` created in the `[WebRequests init]` method will be destroyed at the end of the `if` statement (i.e. pretty much straight away):

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        LoginViewController * loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        self.delegate = loginViewController;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I don't understand why you are creating view controllers in this method; it would be more normal to create the view controller outside of this class (through whatever method) and then register it as the delegate of the `WebRequests` object.

Comment: Yep, that works, I moved declaration in - (void) someMethod, but where is the best way to create it?

Comment: In viewDid load and initWithNibName that not works. Code: 
                LoginViewController * loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        WebRequests * webRequests = [[WebRequests alloc] init];
        webRequests.delegate = loginViewController;

Comment: @user3196922 I would expect the `WebRequests` object to probably be an instance variable of the view controller and for the view controller to be created in the "usual way" (which is off-topic for this question).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm a bit confused by your code but maybe you're looking for something like

```
WebRequests *webRequests = [WebRequests sharedInstance];
webRequests.delegate = self;
```

perhaps in `LoginController`'s `viewDidLoad`.